# R - group_by specific values for a condition

Tags: r

I'd like to randomly sample a dataset with multiple conditions using the group_by function:

```
output<-files %>% group_by(location, time) %>% sample_n(3)
```

However, is there a way to specify within each condition to sample from? Something like this for example:

```
output<-files %>% group_by(location(c[1:2]), time(c[00:00:00-01:00:00])) %>% sample_n(3)
```

So original data frame:

```
Location    Time
1           00:00:00
1           00:02:22
1           00:04:12
1           00:30:00
1           01:00:00
1           01:27:00
1           02:00:00
1           03:00:00
1           03:31:00
2           00:00:00
2           00:03:33
2           00:04:44
2           01:00:00
2           02:00:00
2           03:00:00
3           00:00:00
3           01:00:00
3           02:00:00
3           03:00:00
```

Might look something like this (limited data frame for simplicity's sake):

```
Location    Time
1           00:00:00
1           00:02:22
1           01:00:00           
2           00:00:00
2           00:03:33
2           00:04:44
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  BTW the in the `group_by`, it should be `group_by(location, time)`

Comment: Do you mean `group_by(location %in% 1:2, time %in% c("00:00:00","01:00:00"))`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would help

```
library(chron)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    filter(times(Time)  >= times('00:00:00') & times(Time) <= times('01:00:00')) %>%
    #or use between
    #filter(between(times(Time), times('00:00:00'), times('01:00:00'))) %>%  
    group_by(Location) %>%
    filter(n() >=3) %>%
    sample_n(3)
```